# TypeScript: Typing Recursive Type

Tags: typescript

I have a query that I generate client-side based on user input that looks like this.

```js
const query = {
  "or": [
    {
      "field": "username",
      "operator": "in",
      "value": [
        "jdoe",
        "jsmith"
      ]
    },
    {
      "and": [
        {
          "field": "email",
          "operator": "matches",
          "value": "/^gmail.com/"
        },
        {
          "or": [
            {
              "field": "last_sign_in",
              "operator": "lt",
              "value": 1599619454323
            },
            {
              "field": "last_sign_in",
              "operator": "gt",
              "value": 1489613454395
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

However, in an effort to migrate this to a succinct typescript representation I am struggling with making it work quite how I want it.

I have these definitions:

```js
type Operator = 'eq' | 'in' | 'matches' | 'lt' | 'gt';
type Condition = 'and' | 'or' | 'not';

interface SimpleQuery {
  field: string;
  operator: Operator;
  value: any;
}

interface Query {
  condition: SimpleQuery[] // here I want `condition` to come from the type Condition
// I have tried these solutions involving [{ x of y }] https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24220
}
```

---

Here are the errors I get from the TS compiler:

```
A computed property name in an interface must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.
A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.
Cannot find name 'key'.
'Condition' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

I have tried this with

```
type Query = {
    [key in Condition]: SimpleQuery[];
}
```

with this approach typescript wants me too add all the missing conditions too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do a recursion here ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8pBOBDYB7eUC8UDkECO2UAPjgJYB2hJ2AtsgMYAWEAzlTgDbDvYDm3AbgBQoSFADCKcgBNSwUlMw5EMnmh7kUgoUIrAI8AGaJ60AMqkaYDhACKAVwMgoAbyFQoh0hA7SAXFAswPAUvMIeKAjIaAFwBtHw4VAAbogcjgEqIMIAvjqi0A5OSm4eANoA1hDOFBJSsvJSALoA-AEAgvBIIAA8FlY2RfDOJEMgAHy5OvRSQVB4jsMBYyXuUABEaOsBZWsepR6H614+0tsb9iwG5Ig0EOsANHtHkfGo8OfrFI-PHuup6XuO1+RwAVtIUPcnocYRtQSwaHJGOsQU1njloYcDjD1iozsDYViQTiTr5PhA6KQOD9CTjXkh3p86MAmKwabS-gDHJ8APQAPV4lI4ADoZjQeSiORjia4ZX8tgSOUSlbDjt4yQF1hxEEEAPosUi8ci676YlXyqKMzVcdnmjZcoFQACMAFYAJxugBsTrdABYXb6AMwAJkDcsO0rt2PNatOn21eoNRpN5FtMfpCU+-DTKv+aW5ASdvoAHF6nYH-UG3S6zTGAO7wKS8c5O0NQHk8qD2cgQAAekHo+mk4Y8kfN0dzeJgHx2TXbne7fYHQ5HUDHHLRUtR6LWaJyQA)):

```js
type Operator = 'eq' | 'in' | 'matches' | 'lt' | 'gt';
type Condition = 'and' | 'or' | 'not';

interface SimpleQuery {
  field: string;
  operator: Operator;
  value: any;
}

type Query = {
  [key in Condition]: Array<SimpleQuery | Query>;
}

const query: Query = {
  "or": [
    {
      "field": "username",
      "operator": "in",
      "value": [
        "jdoe",
        "jsmith"
      ]
    },
    {
      "and": [
        {
          "field": "email",
          "operator": "matches",
          "value": "/^gmail.com/"
        },
        {
          "or": [
            {
              "field": "last_sign_in",
              "operator": "lt",
              "value": 1599619454323
            },
            {
              "field": "last_sign_in",
              "operator": "gt",
              "value": 1489613454395
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this would be the most accurate type to describe the objects you described::

```
type Operator = 'eq' | 'in' | 'matches' | 'lt' | 'gt';

type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type Condition = UnionKeys<OperatorExpression>;

interface FieldCondition {
  field: string;
  operator: Operator;
  value: any;
}

type BinaryExpression<T extends PropertyKey> = {
    [P in T] : [FieldCondition | OperatorExpression, FieldCondition | OperatorExpression]
}
type UnaryExpression<T extends PropertyKey> = {
    [P in T] : [FieldCondition | OperatorExpression]
}

type OperatorExpression = BinaryExpression<"and"> | BinaryExpression<"or">  | UnaryExpression<"not"> 


const query: OperatorExpression = {
  "or": [
    {
      "field": "username",
      "operator": "in",
      "value": [
        "jdoe",
        "jsmith"
      ]
    },
    {
      "and": [
        {
          "field": "email",
          "operator": "matches",
          "value": "/^gmail.com/"
        },
        {
          "or": [
            {
              "field": "last_sign_in",
              "operator": "lt",
              "value": 1599619454323
            },
            {
              "field": "last_sign_in",
              "operator": "gt",
              "value": 1489613454395
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8pBOBDYB7eUC8UDkECO2UAPjgJYB2hJ2AtsgMYAWEAzlTgDbDvYDm3AbgBQQ0JCgBVcqRTkA0hBAsAPABUAfJiiqoEAB7AI5ACYttUAPxQA1opQAzcwC4o5CADcI8YWOgBhWWNSYBlyLSlQhSVlOC9kNABRPTB4VhZQ9WEhCkN4e0R6aAAxUggOYwCTYNCoAG8hKCh7UvKXFmB4Cl5hRpQEePgXWKRUbwaod0QOAFcIF0RyEGEAXxFfKAAhCkR4ECSUtNC1XQMjUygABXg+r1AozSx6xsaAbQuoCm0AXSgXF5KyhVAtVZMRYP1RvtUix0rIADRQAHlSpBEKgkjDAZQw6yL5CVbrKQ7PbJaGw8jHfSGExmK43eB3RQPOrjV7vT6qH5-JFAqposIYiGJUk48h41aicDQTGQkUwmpYLbkYnY+WyZQAIgWxg1mhISpVcvJmrQusaJCJu1Vxo15BQwDNImy5Fy+UKUAAirNdizGvRgfyhkL4NbQvinf7yO0oHhvSAg3FZQc1WFHuMNaa-qzfc9GhrmoCNS4NdMWF5lTQIBq4dm8-SBkWoBqKNXa03JjMq1nc7mNQArYwoKs1nvPfssGjBRgatt43PLEfPJ49rUmRsvNuNZejvMF8qNjUQOikDitndj+ujA90YBMVhn8-tqazA8AegAerxjxwAHT+mivjO54LpuObnhm8DrqBubbo+u4tDqxYcIg7QAPrpLw5CoS2i5wXWwYHlwD54U+naNgAjAArAAnNRABs5HUQALJRTEAMwAExsdBzwgSRsFwfmCGEShwDoaQmHYeQxF4RmBHFvwMmCR2L4uORTEABz0eRbEsex1GUTxjSrHBc47iZPZmcZ4zikAA)

This version enforces correct arity of logical operators (using tuple types) and derived the `Condition` union based on the operator union instead.

Comment: Hi, this is a great answer because as a basic TS user I was able to learn some more advanced stuff, so thank you for that. For my use case I extended you answer to use `type Expression<T extends PropertyKey> = {
  [P in T]: [FieldCondition | OperatorExpression][]
}` Because I want to be able to have more than 2 expressions that can be ANDed or ORed. However, this also allows for just a single thing to be ANDed which I am not sure how to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the query interface you want? It'll work on your `query` example but not sure it's to the level of detail you want...

```js
interface Query {
   [key:string]: (SimpleQuery | Query)[]; 
}
```

Comment: in this case you can use `and123` instead of `and` etc, what isn't acceptable I guess.